# Applying LIKE function on column

Tags: sql, teradata

How can I in Teradata apply LIKE function on column name.
I wrote the following code:

```
SELECT *
FROM sb
LEFT JOIN asa
ON asa.column_1 LIKE '%sb.column_2%'
```

This is not returning the result I want
sb.column is COLUMN (with varible values) and not the string I am trying to find.

Edit:
Actually I am trying to find a substring in a string. Which function do I have to use and how?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

'%sb.column_2%' searches for the string 'sb.column_2' within asa.column_1.
You probably need

```
ON asa.column_1 LIKE '%' || sb.column_2 || '%'
```

You could also use

```
ON POSITION(sb.column_2 IN asa.column_1) > 0
```

But both will always result in a product join which will consume a lot of CPU unless at least one table has a low number of rows. Your DBA will definitely not like that :-)

This join probably indicates a bad datamodel, it should be fixed first thus avoiding bad joins like this.